# How to keep assembly instructions of asm functions in c file unchanged when creating the executable for mac os x lion 10.7

Tags: function, assembly, x86, clang, inline-assembly

Here is the asm function in c file copyed from inject-bundle project:

```
asm void mach_thread_trampoline(void)
{

    // Call _pthread_set_self with pthread_t arg already on stack
    pop     eax
    call    eax
    add     esp, 4

    // Call cthread_set_self with pthread_t arg already on stack
    pop     eax
    call    eax
    add     esp, 4

    // Call function with return address and arguments already on stack
    pop     eax
    jmp     eax

}
```

After gcc (i do the work on mac os x lion 10.7.4):

$gcc -m32 -fasm-blocks  -o a a.c -g

gdb the target, watch the mach_thread_trampoline content in gdb:

```
(gdb) x/17i mach_thread_trampoline

0x1f80 <mach_thread_trampoline>:    pop    %eax
0x1f81 <mach_thread_trampoline+1>:  call   *%eax
0x1f83 <mach_thread_trampoline+3>:  mov    %esp,%eax
0x1f85 <mach_thread_trampoline+5>:  mov    %eax,%esp
0x1f87 <mach_thread_trampoline+7>:  add    $0x4,%esp
0x1f8a <mach_thread_trampoline+10>: mov    %esp,%eax
0x1f8c <mach_thread_trampoline+12>: mov    %eax,-0x8(%ebp)

0x1f8f <mach_thread_trampoline+15>: pop    %eax
0x1f90 <mach_thread_trampoline+16>: call   *%eax
0x1f92 <mach_thread_trampoline+18>: mov    %esp,%eax
0x1f94 <mach_thread_trampoline+20>: mov    %eax,%esp
0x1f96 <mach_thread_trampoline+22>: add    $0x4,%esp
0x1f99 <mach_thread_trampoline+25>: mov    %esp,%eax
0x1f9b <mach_thread_trampoline+27>: mov    %eax,-0x8(%ebp)

0x1f9e <mach_thread_trampoline+30>: pop    %eax
0x1f9f <mach_thread_trampoline+31>: jmp    *%eax
0x1fa1 <mach_thread_trampoline+33>: ret
```

The target added some instructions for the mach_thread_trampoline functions.

Is there any methods to keep the asm functions unchanged?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716884/using-the-naked-attribute-for-functions-in-gcc

Comment: helpful, thanks. Could be more detail?

Comment: According to docs simply adding the attribute *naked* should do the trick although I haven't tried it myself: `void mach_thread_trampoline(void) __attribute__ ((naked))`.

Comment: i did as you said, but it didn't work.

Comment: @VilleKrumlinde : naked attribute isn't supported on x86 targets.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: clang since 3.3 supports it, and so does recent gcc.  Other targets have had it for a lot longer, but it does work on x86 with current compilers.  That comment might have been wrong in 2012, but it's not now.

Comment: @PeterCordes This is a question specifically about os x lion 10.7 and it is not available on the installed version of apple's clang. OS/X Lion came out in 2011.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that you can do that with `gcc`, but you could write the function in `a.asm` & assemble `a.asm` with `nasm`.  `a.asm` would look something like:

```
[BITS 32]
global _mach_thread_trampoline
_mach_thread_trampoline:
; Call _pthread_set_self with pthread_t arg already on stack
pop     eax
call    eax
add     esp, 4

; Call cthread_set_self with pthread_t arg already on stack
pop     eax
call    eax
add     esp, 4

; Call function with return address and arguments already on stack
pop     eax
jmp     eax
```

To use it from C, you'd need `a.h` containing:

```
void mach_thread_trampoline(void);
```

Note that the function is intituled `_mach_thread_trampoline` in `a.asm` &  `mach_thread_trampoline` in `a.h`.  This is because function names have an underscore prepended to them on OS X.  If you moved it to linux, the assembly would have `mach_thread_trampoline` as well because linux doesn't prepend anything.

Answer (score 1):

If you have asm functions of non-trivial size, you should put it / them in separate `.S` files where you can use `.intel_syntax noprefix` if you like, or use NASM like another answer suggests.

But you can use an `asm("");` statement at global scope to work around any compile bugs / weirdness if you want to stick a small function written in GAS syntax into a `.c` or `.cpp`, see the last section of this answer.

---

`asm` as a function type appears to be an Apple extension, it's not supported by (Linux) gcc or clang on the Godbolt compiler explorer.

It looks like it serves the same purpose as `__attribute__ ((naked))` (supported on x86 by mainstream (not just Apple) clang 3.3 and later, and recent GCC).  But @MichaelPetch reports that `gcc` on OS X 10.7 (`gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)`) does *not* support `__attribute__ ((naked))`.

(Newer OS X make `gcc` an alias for `clang`, but older OS X had custom versions of GCC).

**It appears that there's a compiler bug** with the `asm void func(void) {` syntax in the compiler version you're using; it doesn't make sense that it can assume the existence of a frame point and insert stuff like `mov  %eax,-0x8(%ebp)`.  I don't see how that `asm` extension could be useful if the compiler's allowed to do that.  Maybe it doesn't happen at `-O3`, so you might be able to work around it by enabling optimization.

BTW, regular (non-Apple) GCC doesn't support MSVC-style asm blocks, though, only GNU C `asm("instructions");` asm statements.  But Apple's version of gcc that uses LLVM does support it.

---

#### `__attribute__ ((naked))` (not supported by OS X 10.7 gcc)

If you have a buggy compiler that introduces extra instructions into asm blocks, IDK if this will make any difference.  (Even if it was supported, which it isn't on OS X 10.7 `gcc`)

This syntax works on modern clang.  (Not gcc, because it still doesn't support `-fasm-blocks`)

This compiles correctly [on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'__attribute__+((naked))+void+mach_thread_trampoline(void)%0A%7B%0A++++asm+%7B%0A++++//+Call+_pthread_set_self+with+pthread_t+arg+already+on+stack%0A++++pop+++++eax%0A++++call++++eax%0A++++add+++++esp,+4%0A%0A++++//+Call+cthread_set_self+with+pthread_t+arg+already+on+stack%0A++++pop+++++eax%0A++++call++++eax%0A++++add+++++esp,+4%0A%0A++++//+Call+function+with+return+address+and+arguments+already+on+stack%0A++++pop+++++eax%0A++++jmp+++++eax%0A++++%7D%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:38.71822033898306,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang33,filters:(b:'0',binary:'0',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-O3+-Wall+-fasm-blocks+-m32+-nostdlib',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+3.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:100,l:'4',m:63.98278398982241,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+3.3',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:36.017216010177584,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:61.28177966101696,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4) with clang 3.3.  I used "binary" output to make sure I was seeing the real machine code in the object file, so I had to use `-nostdlib` to get it to link.  It avoids distorting your asm with `-O0` or `-O3`, but **I'm using a very different compiler this syntax change is probably not relevant.**

```
__attribute__ ((naked)) void mach_thread_trampoline(void)
{
    // asm block *inside* a function
    asm { 
    // Call _pthread_set_self with pthread_t arg already on stack
    pop     eax
    call    eax
    add     esp, 4

    // Call cthread_set_self with pthread_t arg already on stack
    pop     eax
    call    eax
    add     esp, 4

    // Call function with return address and arguments already on stack
    pop     eax
    jmp     eax
    }
}
```

---

#### Portable GNU C `asm("");`

You can put [Basic ASM statements](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html) at global scope in GNU C.

***This* syntax probably will work around the compiler bug on OS X 10.7**, because we're not using `-fasm-blocks` at all, and the compiler has no chance to think it's inside a function.  It should just assemble this code in the `.text` section.

```
void mach_thread_trampoline(void);   // prototype

// definition: name mangling / leading underscore must be done manually
asm(".globl  _mach_thread_trampoline\n\t"
    "_mach_thread_trampoline:\n\t"
    "pop   %eax\n\t"
    "call  *%eax\n\t"
    ...
    "jmp    *%eax"
);
```

So a naked function could have advantages in C++ where the name mangling is non-trivial.  Probably naked functions are automatically noinline.

If you want really portable, you can use dialect-alternatives like `jmp {*%eax|eax}` so your code works if compiled with `-masm=intel` or not.

I don't recommend using `.intel_syntax noprefix` inside an asm block, and then switching back to `.att_syntax` at the end for the rest of the compiler's code.  It's a hack that breaks if you (or a tool like the Godbolt compiler explorer) compiles with `-masm=intel`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Are you saying that Apple's version of clang disables support for the `naked` attribute, or hasn't incorporated that feature from clang3.3?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: No, I don't have any asm experience on OS X, just stuff I've seen on SO.  Is it not safe to assume that apple's clang is similar to normal clang?  Or is the problem here that the old version of Apple clang on that old version of OS X won't support `__attribute__((naked))`, only `asm void func(void) { asm instructions }`?  But then it breaks the asm instructions by adding in store/reload with EBP-relative addresses.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Are there any online compilers that have Apple clang/llvm available?  I don't have an OS X box locally.

Comment: I don't know of any online.I did run it on one of my MacOS systems running 10.7.x (Lion) and your code with the naked attribute says: `test.c:2: warning: 'naked' attribute directive ignored` . The version of the compiler being used `gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2335.15.00)`

Comment: I can also confirm that the original code from the OP with `asm` on the function does compile under that same version of gcc as long as you use `-fasm-blocks` as an option.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Can you repro the `mov    %eax,-0x8(%ebp)` that gets added in with the OP's version?  That's a compiler bug, right, not something the compiler's supposed to be allowed to do?  Assuming a frame pointer would seem to make that syntax unusable on that compiler, unless it works ok with optimization enabled.

Comment: The OP is using `gcc` in his code. That supports the `asm` directive on a function as well as the Intel/MS syntax inside the inline. If you use Apple's version of clang you no longer have the `asm` directive available to you but it will support the naked attribute. (Apple clang version 2.1 (tags/Apple/clang-163.7.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn))

Comment: I'll have to check the generated coded to see if that gets generated

Comment: @MichaelPetch: oh, apparently I'm confused about OS X.  On recent OS X, `gcc` is just an alias for `clang`, right?  But on older OS X, Apple's `gcc` really is the gcc frontend with an LLVM backend?

Comment: On older ones clang and gcc were separate code bases. gcc was a front end for an llvm backend.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: thanks for the corrections.  I rewrote a bunch of this answer to hopefully stop being wrong, and accurately say where/when you might use the examples.

Comment: Apple's (Lion) `gcc` supports `-fasm-blocks` which is actually what the OP was doing originally. `-fasm-blocks` also works on Lion's clang as well, BUT Apple's clang doesn't support the `asm` on a function (where GCC does). In order to use `asm {` on Apples's clang you will need to compile with `-fms-extensions`. Apple's GCC ignores the naked attribute, where clang doesn't

Comment: I have to investigate but when I used your naked attribute variant (using `-fms-extensions`) with clang the generated code only had a `ret`. Not sure if the entire body of inline assembly was ignored or what (It disappeared) and I wasn't even using optimizations)

Comment: I had to install `gobjdump` onmy old MacOS system to get a good dump, but I can confirm the code generated by the OP is what I also had generated with his code.

Comment: The bizarre reference to ebp below the current stack pointer (which looks like a bug) only exists with unoptimized code.If I use `-O1` it looks correct. It seems the compiler has tried to analyze the inline assembly and botched the job when ESP is modified.