# Jump to Naked function on ARM

Tags: c, assembly, arm, inline

The problem is quite simple.

My code is :

```
__attribute__ ((naked)) void function(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
   _asm("push {r0-r6}\n"
        "       .... ");
   if(checkSomeValue(arg3))
       callSomeFunction(arg1, arg2);       
}
```

The asm code What I expected :

```
push {r0-r6}
....
instruction of if ~ callSomefunction
```

But.. the result is :

```
str r1, [sp+0x0c]
str r2, [sp+0x08]  // back up register for if~ callsomefunction statement
push {r0-r6}
...
```

How can I place my asm code in the beginning of function?

Comment: It looks like you're doing this wrong - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716884/using-the-naked-attribute-for-functions-in-gcc

Comment: As far as I understand you should only be calling assembly in naked function, you are accessing normal C code.

Comment: Thank you :) Appreciate it! I'll post the answer after i fix it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My way :

```
__attribute__ ((naked)) void function(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
    _asm("push {r0-r6}\n"
         "bl calleeFunction\n"
         "pop {r0-r6}\n"
         "b backToOriginal\n"
    );
}

void calleeFunction(int arg1, int arg2, int arg3)
{
   if(checkSomeValue(arg3))
      callSomeFunction(arg1, arg2);      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern c is under no obligation to do actions in any particular order.

Using C11, the instruction

```
atomic_signal_fence(memory_order_acq_rel);
```

is used to impose order on statements. In non-C11 compilers, other compiler-specific commands are used:

```
gnu: __volatile__      
intel: __memory_barrier()
MS: ReadWriteBarrier()
```

Comment: For GNU C without C11 you want `asm("" ::: "memory")` for a compiler barrier.  `__volatile__` on its own isn't even a statement, just something you can use with `__asm__ __volatile__( ... )`.  It's the `"memory"` clobber that gives it the effect of `signal_fence`.  An asm statement without any output operands is implicitly `volatile`.