# Use sparc extended asm in global function

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, sparc

I am trying to write an assembly function without using c prototypes.
For some reason it looks like the gcc doesn't allow to use extended asm in the global context.

Please consider the following code that compiles succssefully:

```
void *g_var;
void foo()
{
    asm ("stx       %%i7, [%0]"
        :"=r" (g_var));
}
```

When I am also trying to define the prototype using asm, as follows:

```
asm(".global foo2\n\t"
    "foo2:\n\t");
asm ("stx       %%i7, [%0]"
    :"=r" (g_var));
```

the compiler give me the following error as if extended asm cannot be used in global context.

> foo.c:151:2: error: expected ')' before ':' token   :"=r"
>   (return_addr));   ^

Please note that when I don't use extened asm as follows, the compiler approves the code:

```
asm(".global foo2\n\t"
    "foo2:\n\t");
asm("jmpl       %o7 + 8, %g0\n\t");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Umm.  *Why* are you trying to do this?  What's wrong with just using `foo()`?  Especially if you mark it as inline.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd I was curious about this too, although on x86 it is useful for bootloaders since x86 doesn't support the _naked_ attribute on a function. He's probably trying to avoid any prologue and epilogue code. With ARM I'm pretty sure you could create a naked function containing basic inline assembly. If you need to make that code appear first in a binary then a linker script is your best friend.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd That's right, I am trying to avoid any prologue and epilogue code. I can't create naked function for sparc as can seen in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716884/using-the-naked-attribute-for-functions-in-gcc). I didn't exactly understand your suggestion, but I found another way - I took foo() generated assembly code, and simply removed the parts I originally wanted to avoid (I will post it tomorrow). Thanks

Comment: @MichaelPetch I get that prologue/epilogue can be an issue (isn't `i7` the stack pointer for sparc?).  That's why I was thinking about inlining (ie `inline void foo (void) __attribute__((always_inline))`).  Seems like it would be even more performant than a call/return from this top level code without making future maintainers of this code cry.

Comment: o7 (output) and i7 (input) are the stack pointer yes. If you make such a function inline with no external linkage (static)then it won't be emitted in the code unless used somewhere and then it will always be inlined inside whatever function it is used from. If you give that inline function external linkage won't the compiler be forced to potentially add prologue and epilogue code because it has to assume the specified calling convention for external linkage must be adhered to (it is of course free to always inline the function inside the current object when needed)

Comment: "prototype" is the wrong word for `.global foo2` / `foo2:`.  What you're doing is defining the symbol in assembly, and you *should* still write a prototype instead of just having it implicitly declared as `int foo2(...)`.  i.e. write `void foo(void);` somewhere separate from the pure-asm definition.

Comment: @PeterCordes, thanks! Good idea.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd, foo2 purpose is to "hook" an existing internal, closed source function of some other program. This is why inlining won't satisfy me.
Let's say the function we hook is bar. So, the first instruction in this function would jmp to foo2 hook, and the auto generated epiloge can override bar registers.

Comment: Ahh.  Hooking.  That makes sense.  That also explains why you didn't need a prototype, since you never really 'call' it.  It does seem odd that your implementation of 'bar' might stomp on registers.  Doesn't sparc have a common calling convention?  Perhaps I just don't understand the details of your hook (it's not necessary that I do).  I guess the only question that leaves is why write it with inline asm rather than pure asm. You can still 'find' the routine's address from c if you declare the function as extern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [GCC Documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html):

> Note that **extended asm** statements **must be inside a function**. Only basic asm may be outside functions (see [Basic Asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Basic-Asm.html#Basic-Asm)). Functions declared with the naked attribute also require basic asm (see [Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes)).

So the answer to your question is that - no it isn't possible to use extended assembler templates outside a function in the global context. As you have found basic assembler statements are allowed.