# How to instrument specific assembly instructions and get their arguments

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm, llvm, instrumentation

Given any C/C++ `source.c` compiled with `gcc`

```
int func()
{
    // bunch of code
    ...
}
```

will result in some assembly (example). . .

```
func():
  str fp, [sp, #-4]!
  add fp, sp, #0
  sub sp, sp, #12
  mov r3, #0
  str r3, [fp, #-8]
  mov r3, #55
  sub sp, fp, #0
  ldr fp, [sp], #4
  bx lr
```

. . . which eventually gets turned into a binary `source.obj`

What I want is the ability to specify: **before each assembly instruction *X*, call my custom function and pass as arguments the arguments of instruction *X***

I'm really only interested in whether a given assembly instruction executes. If I say I care about `mult`, I'm not necessarily saying I care whether a multiplication occurred in the original source. I understand that multiply by `2^N` will result in a shift instruction. I get it.

Let's say I specify **mov** as the asm of interest.

The resulting assembly would be changed to the following

```
func():
  str fp, [sp, #-4]!
  add fp, sp, #0
  sub sp, sp, #12
  // custom code inserted here:
  // I want to call another function with the arguments of **mov**
  mov r3, #0
  str r3, [fp, #-8]
  // custom code inserted here:
  // I want to call another function with the arguments of **mov**
  mov r3, #55 
  sub sp, fp, #0
  ldr fp, [sp], #4
  bx lr
```

I understand that the custom code may have to push/pop any registers it uses depending how much `gcc` "knows" about it with respect to the registers it uses. The custom function may be a [naked function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2716884/using-the-naked-attribute-for-functions-in-gcc)

**WHY**

To toggle a pin to do real-time profiling every time instruction `X` is executed.
To record every time the arguments of `X` meet certain criteria.

Comment: No, gcc only knows how to instrument code it's generating.  You can't get it to instrument on a per-instruction basis, especially not when the source is asm, so the compiler doesn't know what registers / memory it can safely use while profiling.  Making a function call requires saving a return address somewhere.

Comment: @PeterCordes that’s what I want: to instrument code it’s compiling just like -finstrument

Comment: Please **edit your question** to motivate it. Give some concrete example of transformation. From where are the `asm` instruction comming?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the compiler takes C code and generates assembly which gets compiled to binary.

Comment: Never comment your own question. **Edit your question** please.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch before it transforms the assembly into binary, I want to auto insert specific assembly blobs before certain assembly instructions

Comment: Consider that people don't even read any comment you are adding here. You need to edit your question (and you need to work half an hour on it, and make it much longer). Add a sentence about your motivations and context.

Comment: Please provide an example.  The thing you are referring to wraps functions which is relatively trivial, but what you seem to be interested in is completely different, inserting within a function.  And are you talking assembly or machine code level?  (compile time or execution time?).   if compile time then simply compile to assembler then insert the instructions before assembling to an object.

Comment: Your question would have been much better off without any mention of `-finstrument-functions` (It confused me when I saw it last night) . Your question has nothing to do with that option. You want to simply insert a series of instruction(s) before or after any particular instruction in your generated code. That's what you should have asked about in general.

Comment: You are asking many binary or other hacking questions but dont really have the experience or understanding to be doing that kind of work yet.  Need to go write programs and work with the tools more.  Understand them.

Comment: @MichaelPetch I included the -finstrument because that option adds code inside of your original code. How is that not similar?

Comment: Your question comes across that you want to place arbitrary code in relation to the generated code from the `-finstrument-function` option. You would have been further ahead just saying you want to be able to insert code before or after a particular list of instructions (like jump or add) generated by the compiler. Then you just ask how you can achieve that.

Comment: @MichaelPetch ok. Makes sense. I have the perfect example I’ll paste when I’m at a PC. godbolt.com generates assembly from C/C++ code; it’ll help immensely for visualization.

Comment: @MichaelPetch then maybe I’ll get back some upvotes :|

Comment: @old_timer updated

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch updated

Comment: @PeterCordes updated

Comment: But even with the updates, the question stays even more confusing. You have a very imprecise picture of compilers. Spend a few weeks reading about them, then ask a better question. Or don't think of compilers, and spend weeks reading about patching or instrumenting assembler code or binary executables.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I asked exactly what my task requires: instrument specific assembly instructions of a function to be compiled. What is confusing?

Comment: You don't explain how is the assembler code produced (from what source code), and you mention GCC and later only tell that it is completely irrelevant. BTW, you need to tell more about the software you are instrumenting (for example, instrumenting the Linux kernel is different from instrumenting the GNU emacs binary).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch the assembler code is produced by the compiler in the process of compilation. `Given some source file, using gcc will result in some assembly which will eventually be compiled into a .obj`. I stated the high-level steps of compliation.

Comment: But GCC is not the same as any compiler (Clang is *not* GCC), and GCC produces code very differently with different version and different optimization flags. And the code produced by GCC is not optimized the same if it is "kernel like" or "emacs like". So all the details you don't want to tell is are very important. We can't guess what is in your mind. Your vision of compilation is *really* naive. And you are not stating the high-level steps of compilation (for GCC, Gimple matters a lot more than assembler)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch how are optimization flags relevant? I want to know if there is an option in `gcc` to instrument specific assembly instructions. I don't care how much or little is optimized. Once the c/c++ is turned into assembly, I want to instrument specific assembly instructions.

Comment: I believe DynamoRIO is capable of what you're trying to do: http://dynamorio.org/

Comment: @crhodes it looks like this requires an OS and requires calls to the library during the running of the program?

Comment: @Adrian Correct, DynamoRIO targets user space applications. It wasn't clear from your question that you're interested in doing this on baremetal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is unclear (even with the additional edit; the `-finstrument-functions` is *not* transforming assembler code, it is changing the way the compiler works, during optimizations and code generation; it works on *intermediate* compiler representations - probably at the [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) level, not at the assembler or [RTL](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/RTL.html) level).

Perhaps you could code some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) which would work at the [GIMPLE](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/GIMPLE.html) level (by adding an optimization pass transforming the appropriate GIMPLE; BTW the `-finstrument-functions` option is adding more passes). This could take months of work (you need to understand the internals of GCC), and you'll add your own instrumentation generating pass in the compiler.

Perhaps you are [using some `asm`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html) in your code. Then you might use some preprocessor macro to insert some code around it.

Perhaps you want to change your [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) or [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention) (or the way GCC is generating assembler code). Then you need to patch the compiler itself (and implement a new target in it). This might require more than a year of work.

Be aware of various optimizations done by GCC. Sometimes you might want `volatile asm` instead of just `asm`.

My [documentation page of GCC MELT](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/gcc-melt/docum.html) gives many slides and links which should help you.

> Is it possible to do this with any compiler?

Both [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) and [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can study their source code and improve it for your needs. But both are very complex (many millions of lines of source code), and you'll need several years of work to [fork](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(software_development)) them. By the time you did that, they would evolve significantly.

> what I’d like to do is choose a set of assembly instructions - like { `add`,  `jump` } - and tell the compiler to insert a snippet of my own custom assembly code just before any instruction in that set

You should read some book on [compilers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) (e.g. the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)) and read another book on [Instruction Set Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) and [Computer Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_architecture). You can't just insert arbitrarily some instructions in the assembler code generated by the compiler (because what you insert requires some processor resources that the compiler did manage, e.g. thru [register allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_allocation) etc...)

### after edition

> // I want to call another function with the arguments of **mov**
>
> ```
>  mov r3, #0
> ```

This is not possible (or very difficult) in general. Because calling that other function will use `r3` and spoil its content.

> `gcc -c source.c -o source.obj`

is the wrong way to use GCC. You want [optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) (specially for production binaries). If you care about assembler code, use `gcc -O -Wall -fverbose-asm -S source.c`  (perhaps `-O2 -march=native` instead of `-O` ...) then look into `source.s`

> Let's say I specify mul as the asm of interest.

Again, that is the wrong approach. You care about multiplication in the source code, or in some intermediate representation. Perhaps `mul` might be emitted for `x*3` without `-O` but probably not with `-O2`

**think and work at the GIMPLE level** not at the assembler level.

### examples

First, look into the source code of GCC. It is free software. If you want to understand how `-finstrument-functions` really works, take a few months to read about GCC internals (I gave links and references), study the actual source code of GCC, and ask on `gcc@gcc.gnu.org` after that.

Now, imagine you want to count and instrument *how many multiplications are done* (which is *not* the same as how many `IMUL` instruction, e.g. because `8*x` will probably be optimized as a shift machine code instruction). Of course it depends upon the optimizations enabled, and you'll work at the GIMPLE level. You'll probably increment some counter at the end of every GCC basic blocks. So after each BB exit you'll insert an additional GIMPLE statement. Such a simple instrumentation could need months of work.

Or imagine that you want to *instrument loads* to detect, when possible, undefined behavior or addressing issues. This is what the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) is doing. It tooks several years of work.

**Things are much more complex** than what you believe.

<sup>(it is not in vain that GCC has about ten millions of source code lines; [C compilers need to be complex](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/273711/40065) today.)</sup>

If you don't care about the C source code, you should not care about GCC. The assembler code could be produced by [Bones](http://www.call-with-current-continuation.org/bones/), by [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/), by a JVM implementation, by `ocamlopt` etc (and all these don't even use GCC). Or could be produced by some other version of GCC (not the one you are instrumenting).

So spend a few weeks reading more about compilers, then ask another question. That question should mention what kind of binary or of assembler you want to instrument. Instrumenting assembler code (or binary executable) is a lot harder than instrumenting GCC (and don't use textual techniques at all). It extracts first an *abstracted* form of the [control flow graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow_graph) and refines and reasons on it.

BTW, you'll find lots of textbooks and conferences on both source instrumentation and binary instrumentation (these topics are different, even if in relation). Spend a few months reading them. Your naive textual approaches have some 1960-s smells which won't scale and won't work on today's software.

See also this talk (and video): [Matt Godbolt *“What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid”* CppCon 2017](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)

Comment: What’s unclear?

Comment: Your goals are unclear.

Comment: goal is to execute some code before specific assembly is about to be executed.

Comment: I greatly clarified my question; you may have to modify your answer?

Comment: I don’t care about multiplication in the source code. I care about the `mul` instruction

Comment: Then you should not care about C or C++ compilers. Work only on assembler code. Don't even mention GCC in your question. I could use Ocaml or SBCL, and I won't use GCC.

Comment: What? I want the compiler to do the instrumentation. How should I not care about the compiler???

Comment: What about code produced by an Ocaml compiler, but Clang, by SBCL, by the JIT generation inside a JVM. None of them are using GCC..... So you should not even mention GCC in your question. My answer is GCC specific! And you (or your client) could use Clang instead of GCC!

Comment: But I'm using `gcc` so those are irrelevant

Comment: I really want to delete this so I can re-post it. It's changed too much. Please vote to close it. It won't let me delete it. I've already voted to close it.

Comment: `that is the wrong approach` - you're assuming I want to detect whether a multiply in the source code occurred; I do not. I really just want to detect when the `mul` instruction was executed.

Comment: Then don't care about the compiler at all. And instrument only the assembler code. This is a different and harder problem (which should not even mention any C thing).